# How to autoscroll with Javascript a Class of ReactJS project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a web page that I want scroll automatically but the webpage is in reactjs. It has a classname called "ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer", I just want create a script for scroll down automatically but it doesn't work!

I will put my code:

```
  function autoScrolling(){
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer")[0];
    element.scrollTo(0, 1000);
    //window.scrollTo(0, element.scrollHeight);
  }
autoScrolling();
```

But it only prints a number but doesn't do nothing... I tried a lot of things but nothing works...

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to scroll the contents of the element, use [`element.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) instead of scrolling the `window`.

Comment: I tried with scrollTo but still it doesn't work :/ @Bergi